# React prop being marked as undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have been working on a nodejs website until I ran until a really stupid error which had me stopped for a solid hour. All of my other redux actions work except for the logout which gives me this error.
Failed prop type: The prop `logout` is marked as required in `Logout`, but its value is `undefined`.
Here is the code for the logout component

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../../actions/authActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export class Logout extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link onClick={this.props.logout} to="#">
          Logout
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { logout })(Logout);
```

Here is the action code

```
export const logout = () => {
  return {
    type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS
  };
};
```

The value is clearly defined. Please let me know what here is not working

Comment: As I know you can't bind an action to the component directly. You have to use `dispatcher`. https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#dispatch

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena. I changed the action to export const logout = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS });
};
However I am still receiving the same problem

Comment: This is a `React` website, not a `Node.js` website.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,

If my redux understanding is correct, I cannot export the class and connect as well. So I had to remove the class export and change it to this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { logout } from "../../actions/authActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Logout extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    logout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link onClick={this.props.logout} to="#">
          Logout
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
  // error: state.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logout })(Logout);
```